# ModuleNotFoundError for all my python pip imports on Terminal only

Tags: python, powershell, import, terminal, python-import

All my pip installed modules work fine using vscode, e.g. numpy, opencv-python, requests but when I run a program using terminal with windows powershell, I get ModuleNotFoundError for all my imports.

running python on terminal works but importing any of my pip installed modules get ModuleNotFoundError

running pip list on terminal
works and shows all my modules

I tried using python -m program.py but that gives "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: Relative module names not supported"

I checked that my python path variables were correct

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a virtual environment?

Usually is best practice and it might solve your issue and at the same time, avoiding shot yourself in the foot every time you install some libraries that make undesired changes...

On Windows is something like:

```bash
$ python -m venv venv
$ .\venv\Scripts\activate
```

Also, have you considered use a proper terminal? Usually I use some UNIX system either MacOS or some Linux distro, but with my company laptop, the best solution that I've found to stop fighting with the Powershell, was to use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)